# What to do with off topic questions not belonging on meta or stackoverflow

Tags: support

Once in a while I see questions that are off topic but not belonging to either meta or stackoverflow. On such case, how should we mark the off topic question?

Edit:
What I'm asking is when marking as off topic, I can only choose meta and stackoverflow as correct place, what if the question doesn't belong to either site?

Comment: Though there are only two "belongs on..." options shown in that box, you also have the option of **not** ticking either the Meta or StackOverflow boxes, this then effectively means "it belongs somewhere else"

Comment: There can only ever be a maximum of five other destinations to suggest when voting to close as "off topic". Since we rarely see anything prime for another SE site besides SO, we haven't added any other options. As has been mentioned, flag it and use the "other" option and mention where you think the question belongs.

Comment: Maybe we could also add [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) -- though it might be hard to distinguish them from SO at times :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vote to close as off-topic, if you don't have the necessary reputation to do that you can alternatively flag as off-topic, so that a moderator can close the question.

If the question would fit on any other SE site, you can flag for a moderator and explain which site you think it should be migrated to. Moderators have the ability to migrate to any site in the SE network.

Completely off-topic questions should also be deleted a while after they were closed, they just clutter up the site with stuff that just doesn't belong on the site.

Comment: What I'm asking is when marking as off topic, I can only choose meta and stackoverflow as correct place, what if the question doesn't belong to either site?

Comment: Then you need to flag for a moderator, they can migrate everywhere. Just use the "other" reason for that.

Comment: Yes, what Fabian said.  We can migrate to any site, just flag the question if it looks like a good question for here.